# Is property based testing easily setup in a hardhat project?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, brownie

I've initially started solidity development using the python brownie framework, however I am thinking of transitions over to hardhat to keep all codebases(frontend&backend) language consistent i.e. javascript. So I'm trying to weigh the pros and cons of each framework and in particular whether property based testing which is quite easy to [setup in brownie](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tests-hypothesis-property.html) is possible in hardhat with minimal additional setup?

Answer (score 0):

The closest framework I found for property-based testing in HardHat is fast-check:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-check

It is not oriented to blockchain testing, but you can customise the *arbitraries*.